# Writing tilde in footnote url

Tags: footnotes, tilde

I try to write footnote in my file as

```
\footnote{http://chasen.org/\~taku/software/yamcha/}
```

But the tilde is compiled as `/âˆ¼` in my web browser. So it can not reach the webpage.

I tried using package URL as following, but the same problem occurs.

```
\footnote{\url{http://chasen.org/\~taku/software/yamcha/}}
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. The great thing with stackexchange, is that a lot of questions have already been asked... and answered. So it is worth to try searching if someone already had the same issue as you have -> you might get a solution even quicker than if you ask it again. This said, for all that, do not hesitate to ask a new question! A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: It sounds like a font issue to me. Try to save the tex-file in unicode format, and maybe add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your code. Url should treat `~` as a letter so `\url{http://bla.bla.bla/~home/test}` should work.

Answer (score 2):

With package `url` use:

```
\footnote{\url{http://chasen.org/~taku/software/yamcha/}}
```

and *not* `\~`, which is a command for the tilde as accent, eg `\~n`